# Making a table using FullPage.js

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a website using fullpage.js as a baseline. I cannot figure out why my tables are not formatting properly inside each section, i.e setting border colours will not work. Any help is appreciated :)

(New coder that wants to learn everything)

```css
.tour-table {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tour-table tr {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tour-table">
  <tr>
    <td> Test1 </td>
    <td> Test2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show your table code please. What its look like, what is your expectation.

Comment: Well, I couldn't get much information out of you description. I think the first thing you can do is to open chrome inspector and inspect the weird part of your page to see what css properties are making it look weird. I am almost certain that you table inherited some css property from the parent div (or from fullpage.js you may say) and overrides your own css properties. If that is the case, you can either make your properties !important or use some advanced styling techniques.

Comment: Code added above